# getResources().getString() is not defined for my class

Tags: java, android, resources, getresource

Here is a string in my `res/values-es/strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="jcq1">Text text text textttttttttt</string>
```

Here is where I use it in my java code:

```
jc.add(new Question("42", "21", "33", "29", 0, getResources().getString(R.string.jcq1), -1));
```

It is giving me this error:

```
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Quiz
```

Where `Quiz` is the name of the class where the java code resides.  All other example code for the method `getResources()` seem to use it the same way I have without problem.  What isn't my implementation of it working?

**EDIT**

```
public class Quiz {

    public Quiz(Context c) {

                    jc.add(new Question("42", "21", "33", "29", 0, c.getResources().getString(R.string.jcq1), -1));
                    // 300 other lines pretty much identical to the one above follows...
```

Comment: Can you post the Quiz class code? I am wondering if you can use something like context.getResources() etc.

Comment: Edited opening post to include Quiz class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResources()` is a method of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29). If your `Quiz` class is not a subclass of `Context` (such as `Activity`, etc), then you must pass in a valid `Context` and call `getResources()` on that `Context`.

Comment: Just updated my `Quiz` code in my opening post.  I think that solved it.  Just got to figure out how to test if it actually pulls the Spanish version of the string now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The examples you're looking at probably expect this code to be used in an `Activity` class, which your `Quiz` class clearly is not. You need a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) for [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29).

Comment: Just updated my Quiz code in my opening post. I think that solved it. Just got to figure out how to test if it actually pulls the Spanish version of the string now. Thanks!